# Ao correr dá-me um erro e não consigo identificar

Tags: c

Eu corro o meu programa e dá tudo bem até chegar ao 
`"l[strlen(l) - 1] = l[strlen(l)]; while (fgets(ll, sizeof (ll), "EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt") != NULL)"`, (fazendo o debug consegui descobrir onde crashava), mas não estou a conseguir resolver o problema, em baixo está o código:

```
while (camp<5) {
    printf("Altere Jogos da Liga dos Campeões %d: ", camp+1);
    scanf("%s", Jogos[camp].campeoes);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    camp++;

    char l[20] = "Liga dos Campeões";
    char ll[20] = {l};
    fgets(l, sizeof(l), stdin);
    l[strlen(l) - 1] = l[strlen(l)];

while (fgets(ll, sizeof (ll), "EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt") != NULL)
    if (strstr(ll, l) != NULL)
    {
        memset(l, NULL, 1000);
    }
    fclose("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt");

feventosDesportivosFutebol = fopen("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt", "w");
                            if (feventosDesportivosFutebol != NULL) {
                                fprintf(feventosDesportivosFutebol, "\n\nLiga dos Campeões:\n\n");
                                for (camp = 0; camp<5; camp++) {
                                    fprintf(feventosDesportivosFutebol, "%s\n", Jogos[camp].campeoes);
                                }
                            }
                            fclose(feventosDesportivosFutebol);
```

e aqui o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me poderia ajudar?

Então o meu código é este:

```
while (camp<5) {
                        printf("Altere Jogos da Liga dos Campeões %d: ", camp+1);
                        scanf("%s", futebol[camp].campeoes);
                        while (getchar() != '\n');
                        camp++;
                    }
                    feventosDesportivosFutebol = fopen("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt", "w");
                    if (feventosDesportivosFutebol != NULL) {
                        fprintf(feventosDesportivosFutebol, "\n\nLiga dos Campeões:\n\n");
                        for (camp = 0; camp<5; camp++) {
                            fprintf(feventosDesportivosFutebol, "%s\n", futebol[camp].campeoes);
                        }
                    }
                    fclose(feventosDesportivosFutebol);
```

Aqui o código funciona bem, só que ao esrever para o ficheiro (ex. sporting - benfica), só fica registado sporting. E procurei pela net alguma ajuda e encontrei aquilo de comparar strings mas não estou a conseguir enquadrar e por isso dar erro, será que me podem ajudar pf?

Answer (score 3):

A função `fgets` precisa de um "file pointer" (FILE*) para ler um arquivo.
Para obter um file pointer é preciso "abrir" o arquivo, com a função `fopen`.
A função `fclose` "fecha" o arquivo referenciado por um "file pointer".

```
FILE* fp = fopen("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
   // erro...
}

// while (fgets(ll, sizeof (ll), "EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt") != NULL) // ERRADO!!!
while (fgets(ll, sizeof (ll), fp) != NULL)
{
   // ...
}

// fclose("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt"); // ERRADO!!!
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: José poderia dar uma breve explicação do código?

Comment: peço desculpa faltava o resto do código, poderia rever o que ta mal em todo o codigo pf josé?

Comment: @ricascross: seu código ainda continua com erro no "fgets" e no primeiro "fclose", veja o exemplo que escrevi...crie e coloque aqui um exemplo pequeno, **mas completo**, que possa ser compilado e testado, para facilitar o entendimento (seu e dos leitores do SO)

Comment: eu vou editar e por a duvida!